# Update version iOS App for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manage

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I distributed an app on Apple Store for private distribution on Apple Business Manager (1.0.0), and now I'd like to update new version(1.0.1), I type enough information but I can not submit for review and there is an error like that:

"Unable to Submit for Review
The items below are required to start the review process:
An error has occurred. Try again later."

Please help me fix it or send me a suggestion, thanks.

Comment: You need to scroll throw the screen. Here should be marked with red color what  is missing.

Comment: @Ramis I type enough information and there is no red color is missing, I distribute for private distribution, I also read the information they talk we can not update the new version for private distribution so I'd to know there is any way to update.

Comment: Can it be, that you have couple translations for your app? If it is the case did you provided translations to every language?

Comment: @Ramis I also have Vietnamese and English in my app for translations

Comment: Then choose Vietnamese language and see is here all all items filled.

Comment: I choose the Vietnamese language already, but not working.

Comment: Is your app have In-App purchases or maybe it is not free. It can be, that you need to accept some documents as time by time Apple updates them and needs to be accepted once again.

Comment: Did my suggestions helped you?

Comment: @Ramis, yes, My app has In-App purchases and it's zero, but t see  I add not enough information in my Agreements, Tax, and Banking part, I'm going to add enough and try again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check if you can not submit iOS app:

- Scroll down/up throw the page is here something marked with the red color.
- If an app supports multiple languages separately check everyone language as the field "Whats new in app" must be provided.
- Time by time Apple changes terms and condition which must be accepted before you can submit an app to App Store.